# PowerShell Script Issue - Files do not decrypt with PGP automatically

Tags: powershell, pgp

Ok, I created a PS Script seems to break somewhere in the middle of it and need help understanding why it skips a function. I am new to scripting and I have no idea how to debug so any help would be greatful.

Script Funtions:

1. Pull PGP encrypted files from external server to a specific folder
2. Decrypt the PGP encrypted files and outputs with a .csv extension
3. Move the original files to specific archive folder
4. Copy decrypted files to SharePoint Online library
5. Move decrypted files to specific archive folder

When the script runs it either skips the decrypt process or does not decrypt all the files. If I run the code by itself, it will decrypt the files correctly. If I run the part of the code that does step 2-5 manually, it does not work.

My goal is to make sure it will process steps 1-5 without intervention and somehow put validation in the script, which I have yet to learn how to do.

Validation goals:

1. Confirm files were pulled
2. For each file pulled, confirm there is a decrypted file created
3. Once copied to SPO, confirm all the files that were decrypted are in SPO

Can anyone help me or point me in a direction on how to fix my script, debug, and/or how to perform validation in scripts? I would be beyond grateful!!

```
    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path "\\WebDrive\clientSFTP\From_client\*.*" -File
foreach ($file in $files)
{
    #Write-Output "Retrieving File: $file"
    Write-Output "$file  TO \\servername\records\client\Received\" 
    
    try
    {
            Move-Item -Path "$file" "\\servername\records\client\Received\" -Force 
}
catch
{
    Write-Output "Error pulling down the files. ($file)"
}

}

#Pause script for 10 seconds
Start-Sleep 10
#If I run the below all together it still fails.
#-----------------------    
$DestPath = "\\servername\records\client\Received"
$files = Get-ChildItem $DestPath -File
ForEach($file in $files)
{
   # try
    #{
        $outfile = $file.BaseName
        Write-Output "PGP Procesing: Input=$DestPath\$file, Output=$DestPath\$outfile"
        Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin\gpg.exe" -WorkingDirectory "$DestPath" -ArgumentList "--pinentry-mode=loopback --passphrase passwordhere -o $DestPath\$outfile $DestPath\$file"

    #}
    #catch
    #{
     #   Write-Output "Error during PGP decryption of: $file"
    #}
}
#---------------
#If I run the lines of code between the #------ it will decrypt all the files correctly.

$files = Get-ChildItem "$DestPath\*.csv" -File
ForEach($file in $files)
{
    try {
        Copy-Item -Path "$file" -Destination "\\WebDrive\SpoProfile\Shared Documents\client\02.From_client\" -Force
        Move-Item -Path "$file" -Destination "\\servername\records\client\Received\Archive\Decrypted\" -Force

    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Output "Error Moving file: $file"
    }

}

$files = Get-ChildItem "$DestPath\*.pgp" -File
ForEach($file in $files)
{
    try 
    {
        Move-Item -Path "$file" -Destination "\\servername\records\client\Received\Archive\Original\" -Force
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Output "Error Moving file: $file"
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you receive any error messages? Also can you clarify when it actually works? You said it works when you run the code by itself. What's "the code" in this context, because later you state that you run steps 2-5, which includes the decrypt, but that it does not work.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not give any errors.

When I run the below set of code it still doesnt work. It only works when I run the PGP decryption process by itself does it decrypt all the files.

I will edit my original post because I cannot post it here due to character limitation.

Comment: As for this.. [I am new to scripting and I have no idea how to debug ], then it is vital that you get ramped up on PowerShell, well, scripting in general. Youtube had tons of Powershell videos [for all levels](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=powershell+beginning). [Debug is here](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=powershell+debugging). There are plenty of free web resources as well. For example: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/powershell/index.htm. If you don't understand programming/scriptihg, then, sure, debug isa problem.

Answer (score 0):

You actually have no functions in this posted code.

Never run destructive code (Create, New, Update, Modify, Move, Delete...) without checking yourself first. [This is why the -WhatIf parameter exists.](https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-whatif/)

Anyway, try this refactored code.

```
$DestPath = "\\$ServerName\records\client\Received"
$WebDrive = 'PathToSource'

Get-ChildItem -Path "\\$WebDrive\clientSFTP\From_client\*.*" -File |
ForEach-Object {
    Write-Output "$PSItem  TO \\$ServerName\records\client\Received\" 
    
    Try
    {
        $moveItemSplat  = @{
            Destination = "\\$ServerName\records\client\Received\"
            Path        = $PSItem
            Force       = $true
            ErrorAction = 'Stop'
        }
        Move-Item @moveItemSplat -WhatIf
    }
    Catch {Write-Warning -Message "Error pulling down the files. $PSItem"}
}

Start-Sleep 10


Get-ChildItem $DestPath -File | 
ForEach-Object {
    Try
    {
        $CurrentErrorActionPreference = $ErrorActionPreference
        $ErrorActionPreference        = 'Stop'

        "PGP Procesing: Input=$DestPath\$PSItem, Output=$DestPath\$($PSItem.FullName)"
        $startProcessSplat   = @{
            FilePath         = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin\gpg.exe'
            ArgumentList     = "--pinentry-mode=loopback --passphrase passwordhere -o $DestPath\$($PSItem.FullName) $DestPath\$PSItem"
            WorkingDirectory = $DestPath
        }
        Start-Process @startProcessSplat
    }
    Catch {Write-Warning -Message "Error during PGP decryption of: $PSitem"}
    Finally {$ErrorActionPreference = $CurrentErrorActionPreference}
}

Get-ChildItem "$DestPath\*.csv" -File | 
ForEach-Object {
    Try
    {
        $CurrentErrorActionPreference = $ErrorActionPreference
        $ErrorActionPreference        = 'Stop'

        $copyItemSplat  = @{
            Destination = "\\$WebDrive\SpoProfile\Shared Documents\client\02.From_client\"
            Path        = $PSItem.FullName
            Force       = $true
        }
        Copy-Item @copyItemSplat

        $moveItemSplat  = @{
            Destination = "\\$ServerName\records\client\Received\Archive\Decrypted\"
            Path        = $PSItem.FullName
            Force       = $true
        }
        Move-Item @moveItemSplat -WhatIf

    }
    Catch {Write-Warning -Messate "Error Moving file: $file"}
    Finally {$ErrorActionPreference = $CurrentErrorActionPreference}
}

Get-ChildItem "$DestPath\*.pgp" -File | 
ForEach-Object {
    Try
    {
        $moveItemSplat  = @{
            Destination = "\\$ServerName\records\client\Received\Archive\Original\"
            Path        = $PSItem.FullName
            Force       = $true
            ErrorAction = 'Stop'
        }
        Move-Item @moveItemSplat -WhatIf
    }
    Catch {Write-Warning -Messate "Error Moving file: $file"}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So it's decrypting the files correctly, but the latter portion is failing.

I believe that is due to the line `$outfile = $file.BaseName` and the fact that the latter portion of the script is searching for files based off the file extensions. `BaseName` returns the filename, minus the extension, so if your file was named `banana.csv` `$file.BaseName` would return `banana`